# ElasticSearch - Pass Array of Terms to Filter

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, elasticsearch, ruby-on-rails-5, elasticsearch-rails

I have a query where I would like to pass a dynamic amount of terms to the filter. Is there anyway to pass this as an array? I've tried several different things but always end up with a malformed request error from elasticsearch. I'm using Ruby on Rails with the elasticsearch-rails gem. Here is my query:

```
@products = Product.search(
     query:{
       function_score:{
         query:{
           bool:{
             must:{
               multi_match:{
                 fields: ['brand^5', '_all'],
                 query: "#{query}",
                 fuzziness: "AUTO"
               }
             },

               filter:{
                 bool:{
                   must:[
                     {term: {"brand":"NordicTrack"}},
                     {term: {"product_type":"Treadmill"}}
                   ]
                 }
               }

           }
         },
         field_value_factor:{
            field: "popularity",
            modifier: "log1p"
         }
       }
     }).page(page).per(25)
```

I would like to pass an array like this:

```
array = ['{term: {"brand":"NordicTrack"}}', {term: {"product_type":"Treadmill"}}]
```

Into the "must" statement like this:

```
 @products = Product.search(
     query:{
       function_score:{
         query:{
           bool:{
             must:{
               multi_match:{
                 fields: ['brand^5', '_all'],
                 query: "#{query}",
                 fuzziness: "AUTO"
               }
             },

               filter:{
                 bool:{
                   must: array
                 }
               }

           }
         },
         field_value_factor:{
            field: "popularity",
            modifier: "log1p"
         }
       }
     }).page(page).per(25)
```

However, this causes a malformed request error by ES.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ensure that your array elements are not strings. Your example shows:

```
array = ['{term: {"brand":"NordicTrack"}}', {term: {"product_type":"Treadmill"}}]
```

It should be:

```
array = [{term: {"brand":"NordicTrack"}}, {term: {"product_type":"Treadmill"}}]
```

If you are building the array in ruby, it should look something like this:

```
array = []
array.push term: {"brand":"NordicTrack"}
array.push term: {"product_type":"Treadmill"}
```